# Rewrite rule to highest application version

Tags: url-rewriting, windows-server-2012-r2, url-rewrite-module, iis-8.5

For reasons unknown and unchangeable to me, I have to work with consecutive developement versions of a web service without any version management:
The new version will be activated to be hosted as an application in IIS, simply replacing the current version as a service, while keeping all versions in the virtual directory as subdirectories.

In the `web.config` of the *Default Web Site*, a simple rewrite rule is in place to direct to the application:

```
<rule name="<name>" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
  <match url="<alias_url>" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="<app_directory>/<current_version>" />
</rule>
```

where `<current_version>` has the pattern `v<main_nr>.<sub_nr>` (i.e `v1.3`).

How can I phrase the rule to automatically choose the highest version?

---

```
Windows Server 2012 R2 | IIS 8.5 | URL Rewrite 2.0
```

Comment: IIS itself won't know what is a version and what is the latest. You'd better rewrite to <app_directory>/latest and in your CI/CD script, copy the latest version to that path.

Comment: @LexLi thx. I know, and I could also just alter the rule by hand. but I thought more about or in the direction of regex matching, or any sort of built in function for pattern matching/number parsing...anything that could be phrased into a rule to replace the path with the highest number present as directory names...any idea?